# Outlook defaults to SSLv3 after windows update

Tags: postfix, email-server, outlook

I have disabled SSLv3 protocols in my postfix configuration, and outlook still tries to connect and I am getting error: SSL_accept:failed in SSLv3 read client key exchange A

My main.cf

```
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols  = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols           = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_protocols            = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

Thunderbird works without a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to remove the update then check if outlook can work properly? According to my research, here seems to be a similar question: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/postfix-tls-and-broken-ms-outlook-after-windows-october-2022-update.86777/#post-584554

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what you have done at the client.  Depending on which version of Windows and which version of Outlook you are using there can be extra configuration required on the client to enable and use modern TLS.

For Windows 7 check Windows Update (or equivalent) for the TLS update.  [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)

Be sure to read the article fully, as it is not sufficient to merely install the updates.  You must also create new registry keys to actually enable the new protocols.

> Enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on Windows 7 at the SChannel component level

> Per the TLS-SSL Settings article, for TLS 1.1 and 1.2 to be enabled and negotiated on Windows 7, you MUST create the "DisabledByDefault" entry in the appropriate subkey (Client) and set it to "0". These subkeys will not be created in the registry since these protocols are disabled by default.

Comment: I am using Windows 10pro 21H2 which was updated 2 days ago (than is when Outllok stoped to work). For Office I am using Outlook Professional Plus 2019.

Comment: And using NMAP if I check mail server chipers: nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 587 mail.yyyycom | grep TLSv   or grep SSL I can only see TLSv1.2. So I don't know why would outlook try to connect on SSLv3